# $f(x)=\arctan(1+x^2)$ - Global minimum

Tags: analysis

I know that $\arctan(x)\colon \mathbb{R} \to (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, therefore it's global minimum is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I also know that: $\arctan'(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Usually to calculate a minimum you would need:

1. $f'(x) = 0$
2. $f''(x) > 0$

We have $f(x)=\arctan(1+x^2)$

How do I proceed?

I know that $\arctan'(u(x)) = \frac{1}{u(x)^2+1} \cdot u(x)'$

So we get $f'(x)= \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2+1} \cdot {2x} = \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2+1}$

So we can calculate $f'(x) = 0 \leftrightarrow x=0$ and $\arctan(1+0) = 0.785398163$

Do I now just caluclate $f''(0)$ by using the quotient rule for derivatives?

I've calculated $f''(x)$ as followed:

$u'= 2$,   $v' = 4x(x^2+1)$, $u = 2x$, $v=(1+x^2)^2+1$.

Applying the quotient rule:

$\frac{2(1+x^2)^2+1-(4x(x^2+1)\cdot2x)}{((1+x^2)^2)^2}$, putting in $0$ we get:

$\frac{2(1+0)^2-(4\cdot 0(0^2+1) \cdot 2 \cdot 0)}{1} = 2$, therefore our global minimum is $Min(0,0.785)$

Comment: You should start with finding $d/dx f(x)$ but remember $f(x)$ is *not* arctan of x, but more complicated. Need chain rule.

Comment: @coffeemath I've edited a little bit and found how you get to $f'(x)$.

Comment: Yes your calculation is right. And the min is $\pi/4=.785398...$ Saying min is $\pi/4$ when $x=0$ gives the *exact* value of the min, which is sometimes preferred over an approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without derivatives:

1. We know that $\operatorname{arctan}(x)$ is strictly increasing.
2. $1+x^2$ has its minimum for $x=0$ and is positive.

Hence $\operatorname{arctan}(1+x^2)$ has its global minimum for $x=0$.

Comment: That's pretty smart, don't know if there's something about that in my manuscript (I'm not studying mathematics).

In general my approach would be correct though right?

Comment: @DidseaJ Yes, but you can obtain the result without the second derivative. The first derivative is negative for x<0 and positive for $x>0$, hence at $x=0$ is the minimum. (You should have such a theorem).